# getting error Unknow Host : www.google.com

Tags: java, html-parsing, htmlunit

i want to parse the webpage, iam using htmlunit , when iam running the code, iam getting below error.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class scrapImage {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception      { 
          URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
          //WebClient webClient = new WebClient(Opera);     
          WebClient webClient = new WebClient();    
          HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);    
          //get list of all divs      
          final List<?> images = currentPage.getByXPath("//img");      
          for (Object imageObject : images) {           
              HtmlImage image = (HtmlImage) imageObject;            
              System.out.println(image.getSrcAttribute());       
              }         //webClient.closeAllWindows();           } } 
          }
      }
```

***Error Message:***

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:196)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:530)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:480)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:251)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:97)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1430)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1388)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:325)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:386)
    at htmlunit.scrapImage.main(scrapImage.java:16)
```

Can anyone let me know the solution for above exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think its problem with your net connection or your firewall may block the java program to access internet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are behind the proxy or firewall. Check your current firewall status in your system.Also, if it  is related to proxy, you can modify the code like this.

```
System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
System.getProperties().put( "proxyHost", "your proxy host name" );
System.getProperties().put( "proxyPort", "85" );
```

May be this will help you.

Comment: when i get the proxy name by InetSocketAddress addr = (InetSocketAddress) proxy.address(); and System.out.println("proxy hostname : " + addr.getHostName()); , getting null pointer as addr itself null and proxy is null. Please can you guide me

Comment: Give the name of your proxy server because all the requests are routed through this.Give your proxys IP address instead of above one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is some trouble with the Internet connection or you are behind a proxy ,

set the proxy settings (Host/Port/Username/Password) if this is the case.